# Using ng-repeat on JSON object keys to generate tabs in md-tabs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I was hoping to generate tabs for each key of a JSON object. Tabs are not visible and no error is shown in console. I could generate a table but not tabs based on keys. Please advise.

Here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pxa076rs/3/

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])

  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.statuses = JSON.parse({
      "One": "First Tooltip",
      "Two": "Second Tooltip",
      "Three": "Third Tooltip"
    });


  });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<md-content class="md-padding">
  <md-tabs class="" md-selected="selectedTab" md-align-tabs="top" md-border-bottom md-autoselect md-dynamic-height>

    <md-tab ng-repeat="(key, value) in statuses">
      <md-tab-label>
        {{key}}
        <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">
          {{value}}
        </md-tooltip>
      </md-tab-label>

      <md-tab-body>
        <md-list>
          <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="design in status.designs" ng-click="showDesign(design._id)">
            <img ng-if="design.images[0]" ng-src="{{design.images[0]}}" class="md-avatar" alt="no img" />
            <img ng-if="!design.images[0]" src="https://das4vxwadkuqo.cloudfront.net/missing.png" class="md-avatar" alt="no img" />
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
              <h3>{{ design.name }}</h3>
              <h4>{{ design._created_at }}</h4>
              <p ng-bind-html="design.description"></p>
            </div>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
      </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>

  </md-tabs>
</md-content>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Even though you have shared your code on JSFiddle, it's nice to have some code on the question as well which can provide context of your problem. Consider adding the code where you are actually facing the problem and then the link to jsfiddle is more useful.

Comment: First of all you have a issue in your JS. You're trying to parse an object in the `JSON.parse`. Remove the `JSON.parse` call and assign the object directly and your code works.